# Open API 3.0 RequestBody not accessible in req.swagger.params as it is coming in undefined in node API

Tags: node.js, openapi, swagger-3.0

When I am trying to access the requestBody it is giving me error cannot access undefined.
Then I checked by printing the **req.swagger.params** it looked like this:

```
  { _id: 
     { path: '/v0/users/config/{_id}',
       schema: [Object],
       originalValue: '123',
       value: '123' },
    undefined: 
     { path: '/v0/users/config/{_id}',
       schema: [Object],
       originalValue: [Object],
       value: [Object] } }
```

Not able to understand the reason of requestBody coming in undefined key name.

How do I access the requestBody now?

Comment: Please post your Node.js code and the OpenAPI definition for this operation with the request body? How are you sending the request - are you sure the request body is actually sent?

Comment: @Helen I found the issue, We have to mention the name for the requestBody as well in routes which was not mentioned in OpenAPI 3.0 documentation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found the solution posting the solution for other people who face the same issue. Its not mentioned in its documentation.

```
requestBody:
  x-name: body 
  content:
    application/json:
      schema:
        required:
        - name
        properties:
          name:
            type: array
            items:
              type: string
            description: Updated name of the pet
          status:
            type: string
            description: Updated status of the pet
```

We have to mention the name of requestBody in **x-name**